# Backend gets a pdf from a third-party. How can I send it via REST api to my client?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, express

I get a pdf from a third party.
I save the file on S3. I can see the file on S3 and when I open it I can see my PDF.
However, when I passed the pdf to the client and check it on Postman I get an empty PDF.

Here is my code:

```
public async getReportFromThirdParty(token) {
    const params = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
    }  

    let report = {};
    report = await axios.get(`https://api.thirdparty.com/api/get-pdf`, params);
    return report.data;
}


app.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
   const token = 'abcde-secret-token';
   const pdf = await getReportFromThirdParty(token);
   await saveToS3(pdf) // <---- I checked and it saves the file properly on S3 as PDF
 
   res.contentType("application/pdf");
   return res.status(200).send(pdf); // <--- this returns an empty pdf file
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We cannot possibly help you without your code meeting the standards of a [mre] - for starters, it's not clear at all what `getReportFromThirdParty` actually returns and whether that return type will be useful to pass directly to `res.send`.

Comment: The typical response of POST are 200 ok, 204 No content and 201 Created. You can send data back but usually not a BLOB. It's possible that your 'app' ( that we have no idea about it) is simply ignoring or stripping out any content if the response code is 204 No Content.  I would suggest you set the response code OR do a following app.get. what happens if you send back basic text or json.

Comment: Re edit: Adding a 200 status to the code doesn't address any of the issues raised in the previous comments.

Answer (score -2):

im going to guess your app is an `node express app` so therefore you likely need to

```
res.sendFile();
```

More info found on the [express site](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendFile)

Comment: OK. I've had another look at the question and it isn't unlikely. It's next to impossible. The code shows that the value of `pdf` is returned from a third party API. That definitely will not be a path on the local filesystem. The value is quite unsuitable for use with `sendFile`.